# Does there exists such a function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

A function from $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that :

a. $f$ is bijective,

b. $f’(0)=1$ (in particular, $f$ is differentiable and therefore continuous at 0), and

c. $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at 0.

I think it exists! But don’t know how to find it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the function would be continuously differenttiable then it's not exist because of the inverse function theorem. Therefore if it exists its derivative must be discontinuous at $x=0$. Unfortunately I can't imagine such function, but if we omit the condition of differentiability and suppose that $f(x)$ is only continuous at $x=0$ then it's not difficult to think up a function which satisfies your conditions.

Comment: Agreed!!!@DF even I am finding it difficult to find such a function

Comment: Can you use some property of the Cantor function or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1 &x\in[-1,+\infty)\\
-x-2 &x\in(-2,-1)\\
x+1 &x\in(-\infty,-2]
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can even get $f(0)=0$ (which I suspect you intended to require but missed writing). For example, let $A=(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$ and define
$$ g : A \to A : g(p/q) = (pq+1)/q^2 $$
where $p/q$ is in lowest terms, and then 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) & x\in A \\
x-1 & x>1\text{ and }x-\lfloor x\rfloor \in A \setminus g(A) \\
x & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

The key insight here is that $f$ only needs to be *injective* near $0$ while satisfying $f'(0)=1, f(0)=1$ -- you can fill in any missed points by letting it behave wildly *far from* $0$, and if there are missed points arbitrarily close to $0$, this then automatically prevents $f^{-1}$ from being continuous there.